# How can I create events with recurrence programatically in either Google Calendar or Outlook using either Zapier or MS Flow?

Tags: google-calendar, zapier, office-online, outlook.com-calendar

I have a number of google calendars that I use to organize tasks and events, and one google calendar that I use for publicity (so others can know what I am doing, if I want them to). I found a simple zapier zap to make an event in the "public" calendar whenever I make an event in any one of the "private" calendars. However, the only way to enforce recurrence on the programatically created events is to make a hard setting inside the zap - in other words, there seems to be no way to transmit recurrence from "old" events to "new" events.

For now, I have a simple stopgap - I organize the "subcalendars" so each contains only one type of recurrence. Then the "zap" can be hardlocked accurately. I consider this a temporary kludge. I would like some way to inherit recurrence between calendars. Since I have both a google account and an outlook account, I have no problem with a solution that uses google calendars and an outlook calendar as an output, or vice versa. For reference, flow also seems to have only outputs for recurrence, but no inputs.

PS - before anyone points me at any desktop apps, I'm really trying to stick with the cloud for this. I have only the one desktop, right now, and nobody has yet repealed Murphy's law, afaik :).

PPS - and, yes, I have seen calendly. It's very good, and I may use it for other stuff, but I did not see anything about it saying specifically what I am "busy" with - just that I am "busy".